# Next.js with next-auth getServerSideProps require authentification

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to make some kind of server middleware that verifies the auth state of a user to render the page. It's working but I want to access the current user if authenticated and authorized without recalling `unstable_getServerSession`.
The function I implemented:

```js
export const requireAuth =
  (role: Role, func: GetServerSideProps) => async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    const session = await unstable_getServerSession(
      ctx.req,
      ctx.res,
      authOptions
    );

    if (!session || (session as Session).user?.role !== role) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: "/auth/login", // login path
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    }

    return await func(ctx); // I want to pass the user here
  };
```

The execution context of that function :

```js
const Page = () => {
  return (
    ...page
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = requireAuth('ADMIN', async (ctx) => {
    // I want to be able to access the currently authenticated user here without
    // repeating the same process above
  return { props: {} };
});
export default Page;
```